# Save Order of Execution

Tags: apex, order-of-execution

I have 2 questions with the Save Order of Execution.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

1. In the link above, it keeps mentioning 'goes through the save procedure' when a record has been updated. Does this mean it follows the following steps:

a. Execute all before update triggers

b. Execute most system validation (not custom)

c. Save record to database

d. execute all after triggers

Or does it mean the following which is taken from the developer guide:

*During a recursive save, Salesforce skips steps 8 (assignment rules) through 17 (roll-up summary field in the grandparent record).*

2. My second question comes is from the following link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MNiTIAW

The question is about the order of execution. If it is System Validation then Before Trigger or the other way round.

Personally, I believe it is Before Trigger then System Validation because System validations only runs before the 'before trigger' when the newly inserted record is submitted from the UI. Is my logic correct?